# Install opencv 3.3.1 (previous version) with homebrew

Tags: opencv, homebrew

I have an issue with not being able to use an integral piece of software due to its dependancy and being compiled with a previous version of opencv. When installing new opencv using homebrew `brew install opencv` I am getting the latest version 3.4. Is there anyway to install a previous version? Edit: On MacOS.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a previous version tap for this. Did you resolve it yourself in the end?

Answer (score 2):

For others with the same problem:

```
$ brew install opencv@3
```

Answer (score 0):

See this other answer about installing different versions of homebrew packages.
[Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)